# objective C on how to make connection of two .xib file

Tags: objective-c

I have been wrote for two interface of .xib file. How to make connection between these two files? When I run the file, the first .xib will appear then after i click the button, the second .xib file will appear and on the top of first .xib file. Thus, i want use the second .xib function to make control of the first .xib file. Thus, there is two .xib file at the end. How to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly, but .xib files shouldn't talk to each other. That's what your controller classes are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The button in your first nib should be making a call to the File Owner (mostly likely a controller or application delegate), which should open the second nib.

For example, in one of my applications, I have this bit of code:

```
- (IBAction)openPreferencesWindow:(id)sender {
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"PreferencePane" owner:self];
}
```

`PreferencePane.xib` being the name of my second nib.